# PHP token-based system

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, mcrypt

I'm building a login system and I want it to be secure so that I can re-use it on several projects. I'm using the function below to encrypt the given password with my secret key (32 chars).

```
function Encrypt($key, $payload) 
{
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(IV_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $payload, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $combo = $iv . $crypt;
    $garble = base64_encode($iv . $crypt);
    return $garble;
}
```

My IV_SIZE is the following:

```
mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC))
```

Before you ask I don't allow users to enter a password. I generate a very complicated and long password for them with everything inside (uppercase, lowercase, digits and symbols). I've also implemented a ban system that allows you to insert a wrong password for a verly limited amount of times and, as if it wasn't enough, I also lock the entire account so that you can't try again even when the ban has expired.

This is the decrypt function still pretty standard:

```
function Decrypt($key, $garble) 
{
    $combo = base64_decode($garble);
    $iv = substr($combo, 0, IV_SIZE);
    $crypt = substr($combo, IV_SIZE, strlen($combo));
    $payload = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $payload;
}
```

Said that it's 2 hours that I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach to issue a login session/cookie. I want to adopt a token-based approach like follows.

As soon as login is successful, I want to store in a cookie the first part of an hash. The entire hash is stored in my DB and it is unique. The second part of it would be something like a salt + sha/md5/base64 (...) of userid, email, timestamp etc. Is it a good approach?

Comment: It really depends on the requirements of your project. If you don't plan on getting a lot of traffic or have plenty of server resources, I suggest using DB as a way of storing sessions and such. The reasoning as that it is more reliable than the others. All you have to do is pretty much save a timestamp. It is persistent in most cases. Users can close the browser, restart their computer, and come back and still have an active session, etc. However, this approach will use more server resources than the other conventional methods as it needs to request the DB every single time a page reloads.

Comment: You just have to weigh which option better suits YOU, rather than choose the one people says is the best

Answer (score 0):

No.

Unless you need to have access to the plain-text password (e.g. if it's a password for a configured SMTP server that you'd use), you MUST NOT encrypt passwords, but *hash* them.
And use [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash) (bcrypt) to hash them; it is specifically designed for this purpose.

<del>Also, it is not made clear in your question what these hashes are for</del>, but it sounds like a flawed choice at best - MD5 and SHA1 shouldn't be used for any kind of security mechanisms today<del>, and if you want to verify the authenticity of something, you should be using a keyed hash function like `hash_hmac()` instead anyway.</del>

Use a generic PHP session to maintain the login state.

It seems to me that you're over-thinking the problem at hand and in turn over-engineering the solution. Keep it simple.

Comment: I don't need plain-text passwords. In my database I'm storing the result of Encrypt() function with base_64 encoding. I then find if there's a match in the database passing the password entered by the user with Decrypt() function. Isn't it good? When there's a match (password is correct) I issue a token that is valid for X days. I generate the token with bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20)); and I use it to identify the logged user in my system. Basically I use this token as an equivalent of the ID of the user and I save it in a cookie.

Comment: Then **hash** the passwords, don't encrypt them. Encryption is two-way, which means that you have access to the plain-texts, and if you have it then a potential attacker may also have it. As for the tokens ... that's the basic mechanism that a regular PHP session uses. In both cases you're over-engineering the solution and most likely missing important details in the process.